# how to create a table with sum of two different queryset

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have the following model in my django app:

```
class Budget_Vendite(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey()
    byproduct=models.ForeignKey()
    quant_jan=models.DecimalField()
    quant_feb=models.DecimalField()
    quant_mar=models.DecimalField()
    price_jan=models.DecimalField()
    price_feb=models.DecimalField()
    price_mar=models.DecimalField()
```

I want to create a dataset that for each byproduct figure out the montly amount given by `quant_jan*price_jan`
Ad example:

```
byproduct   |         jan         |         feb         |            
byproduct_1 | quant_jan*price_jan | quant_feb*price_feb |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define methods in your model, each for each month, example:

```
def january(self):
    return self.quant_jan * self.price_jan
.
.
.

def march(self):
    return self.quant_mar * self.price_mar
```

and call them in your template html in corresponding column

monthly sum:

```
def year_sum(self):
    months = ((quant_jan, price_jan), ...)
    sum = 0
    for month in months:
        sum += getattr(self, month[0]) * getattr(self, month[1])
    return sum
```

Comment: Okey and if I want to figure out the total sum of all byproduct   ?

Comment: Then make another method called total_sum() and call every function inside it and sum your values

Comment: okey your solution work but I want to have ad example a `monthly_sum= list(0 for m in range(12))` in which I fill for each month a `quant_jan*price_jan`

Comment: my first idea is to provide a tuple of tuples, example: ((quant_jan, price_jan), (quant_feb, price_feb),...) and use getattr() to get the values and multiply them

Comment: Could you give me an example editing your quuestion? becouse I'm not good at python yet